# update or replace [] on array field in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

So by mistake, I migrated 68k documents from a table to another, but the problem is  ( i'm a SQL Server DBA learing mongodb):

I need a field ( array ) that has the value:

```
something : [ 000 ]
```

but during the project, I used another `[` and `]`:

```
$project:
{
field_name:[$field_value]
}
```

but the field is already array so the result I got was:

[image]

Vieweing with JASON:

```
"targetMarketCountryCode" : [
        [
            "076"
        ]
    ],
```

is there a way to update;replace this value to remove this quotes `[[]]` and use only one normal array quote `[]`??

I would like to update ALL documents.

I'm trying to replace but with no success:

`db.rep.replaceOne( {"field":[[079]]}), {"Idate":[079]} )`
this is just a test, not the oficial table.

Tests:

```
db.teste.insert({name:"butter",value:[["077"]]})
db.teste.insert({name:"butter",value:[["077"]]})
db.teste.insert({name:"butter",value:[["077"]]})


db.teste.find()

/* 1 createdAt:14/08/2019 13:08:15*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431ef44f85649486e4100"),
    "name" : "butter",
    "value" : [
        [
            "077"
        ]
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:14/08/2019 13:08:21*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431f544f85649486e4101"),
    "name" : "butter",
    "value" : [
        [
            "077"
        ]
    ]
},

/* 3 createdAt:14/08/2019 13:08:22*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431f644f85649486e4102"),
    "name" : "butter",
    "value" : [
        [
            "077"
        ]
    ]
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    db.teste.aggregate({$unwind: "$value"})

    /* 1 createdAt:14/08/2019 13:08:15*/
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431ef44f85649486e4100"),
        "name" : "butter",
        "value" : [
            "077"
        ]
    },

    /* 2 createdAt:14/08/2019 13:08:21*/
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431f544f85649486e4101"),
        "name" : "butter",
        "value" : [
            "077"
        ]
    },

    /* 3 createdAt:14/08/2019 13:08:22*/
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431f644f85649486e4102"),
        "name" : "butter",
        "value" : [
            "077"
        ]
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

db.teste.aggregate([{$unwind:"$value"}, {$out:"teste" }])

db.teste.find()

/* 1 createdAt:14/08/2019 13:08:15*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431ef44f85649486e4100"),
    "name" : "butter",
    "value" : "077"
},

/* 2 createdAt:14/08/2019 13:08:21*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431f544f85649486e4101"),
    "name" : "butter",
    "value" : "077"
},

/* 3 createdAt:14/08/2019 13:08:22*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431f644f85649486e4102"),
    "name" : "butter",
    "value" : "077"
}
```

What I can see is:

1) I have an array with `[["value"]]`

2) Using $unwind I can replace `[["value"]]` to `["value"]`.

3) Uing it to "update" the document, it removes both arrays and replace the value with a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

**For the MongoDB version: 4.2+**

```
db.rep.updateMany(
  {},
  [
    {
      $set: {
        "targetMarketCountryCode": {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$targetMarketCountryCode",0]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

It would replace the 'targetMarketCountryCode' array with its first element in all the documents.

**For lower versions: 2.6+**

```
db.rep.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$targetMarketCountryCode"
    },
    {
        $out:"rep"
    }
])
```

It performs aggregation on the 'rep' collection. The 'targetMarketCountryCode' is unwinded and old data of the collection is replaced with the output of the aggregation query.

Sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5430aa7c780d119a01a6ce"),
    "targetMarketCountryCode" : [
        [
            "076"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5430aa7c780d119a01a6ce"),
    "targetMarketCountryCode" : [
        "076"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you MrSSharma. I'm using Mongodb4.0, so I tested the second answer. the problem is that "targetMarketCountryCode" is not an array anymore. it deleted both `[[` and `]]`. I would like to remove only one `[ ]`. It looks like it's an aray inside an aray right? I would like to use a normal array for this value. I tried to add an array inside the code but I got the error `"$out stage requires a string argument, but found array"`

Comment: and its funny because if I use `db.teste.aggregate([{$unwind:"$valor" }])` i can remove only one `[ ]`.

Comment: @RacerSQL : $out is used with aggregation & it's destructive - you need to be cautious with it, it would replace the entire collection if the provided string(name of the collection) matches with one existing or creates a whole new collection with the output of aggregation query !! Try to use updateMany.

Comment: @RacerSQL The unwind would only open up the first array. Added sample data and output in answer. Srinivasy is right that this would replace the old data in collection with the output of aggregation query, but I believe its one time update and thus we can go with it.

Comment: I'm updating the question with the data I'm using to test.

Comment: @RacerSQL I am firing the same query, but only top-level array is opened up. Here is the output.
 ```{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431ef44f85649486e4100"),
 "name" : "butter",
 "value" : [
  "077"
 ]
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431f544f85649486e4101"),
 "name" : "butter",
 "value" : [
  "077"
 ]
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d5431f644f85649486e4102"),
 "name" : "butter",
 "value" : [
  "077"
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the answers. As i'm using mongo 4.0 I could make this:

```
db.collection.update({ field: [["value"]] }, {
$set: {     
    "field": [ "value" ]},
{ multi: true, upsert: false}})
```